# Very weird DHCP IP range, never seen it before

Tags: networking, router, ip, dhcp

I'm trying to figure out what this DHCP IP range means, it's in a format which I've never seen before.

Am I right in thinking that the range is in the middle? If so, then what the heck is the number at the end for?

[image: DHCP range]

Comment: The range and network addresses are entirely dependent upon the subnet mask. The information you provided doesn’t tell us anything other than you are not using a 255.255.255.0 subnet mask.

Comment: The mask must be /22 (255.255.252.0) or more wide for shown DHCP scope addresses range to be valid.

Comment: This [Subnet Mask Cheatsheet](https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html) may be of value to you, as I find it quite helpful when it's required =]

Answer (score 3):

Usually home networks are Class C subnets aka /24.  So there are 254 valid subnets each with 253 valid addresses.  Usually you set the 3rd octet of the IP address and the range of addresses within the network on separate lines.  Here it looks like you can choose both, but you need both chosen addresses to be in the same subnet.

In that case the red text should disappear if you put in the same number in both the 1st and third fields like:
  192.168.(8).(100)-(8).(200)

Technically there's nothing really preventing you from defining a subnet with more than 253 addresses for your local network. 192.168.8.100 and 192.168.11.200 could be on the same subnet if it was a /22 where the subnet mask was 255.255.252.0 but the code probably isn't that smart because you can't guarantee a subnet will only contain the addresses you want if they aren't well chosen.  A subnet containing 192.168.8.1 and 192.168.12.1 also contains everything up to 192.168.15.255

Answer (score 2):

It's allowing you to set both the 3rd and 4th octets. So you could have a huge range from 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.255.254 (about 2^16 or 64Ki addresses).

Or if it only allows you a single /24, then it's allowing you to pick which /24 you want to use. So you could choose:

- 192.168.0.2 - 192.168.0.254 
   or
- 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.254 
   or
- 192.168.255.2 - 192.168.255.254 
   etc.